# Multiply two matrices element wise with summation

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices 4x2. How can I achieve such multiplication: the output should be a matrix 4x1, where each element is a sum of products of elements in rows in the original matrices.
Like this:

```
    [1 2;
A =  3 4; 
     5 6;
     7 8]

    [1 2;
B =  3 4; 
     5 6; 
     7 8]
```

result C matrix will be:

```
    [1*1 + 2*2;
C =  3*3 + 4*4;
     5*5 + 6*6;
     7*7 + 8*8]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an even neater answer:

```
C = dot(A, B, 2);
```

You essentially want the dot product of the rows. This is one vectorized operation in MATLAB, so more efficient than element-wise product then a sum operation.

Answer (score 2):

My matlab is a little rusty, but try

```
D = A .* B;
C = D(:,1) + D(:,2);
```

The first operation would produce a 4x2 matrix that contains the products of the corresponding elements from A and B, while the second operation adds the products from the same row.

The results you are seeking are also the diagonal elements from the matrix product, so you could use

```
C = diag(A * transpose(B));
```

although that would be terribly inefficient for larger matrices.

Comment: @Ansari: Nice; I didn't know that `sum()` could be used in that manner.

Comment: @Ansari: Great. This is what I was looking for. Your solution works for matrices of any size. If you post your comment as answer, I`ll mark it as right

Comment: Thanks @Alkersan - I answered with an even more concise way of doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Aasmund Eldhuset is mostly correct but I believe the last line should be

```
    C = D(:,1) + D(:,2);
```

as you want to sum each row in the final column

Comment: Apologies. I misread the earlier comment. It's actually correct.

Comment: Actually, you didn't misread it - for about a minute, it actually read `D(1,:) + D(2,:)`, since I had forgotten whether Matlab is row major or column major. However, corrections like this should be posted as a comment (or you can make them yourself when you have gathered enough reputation). :-)